# Searching through array gives no results

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, this

I am creating a website that is going to show all publicly available toilets in an area(it's for a school project). I'm importing a JSON file, parsing it and naming it "toiletData". What I am trying to do is have an object be responsible for defining the criterias of the users search. When the user presses "search", and object is created with the criterias selected, and I'm trying to loop through the toiletData to remove any entries that doesn't fit. The problem is that the function doesn't return the correct array, when searching for specific criteria the function only returns some of the matches, even though there are more.

Code for search object(translated to english):

```
function SearchCriteria() {
    this.name = void 0;
    this.address = void 0;
    this.wheelchairAccesible = void 0;
    this.price = void 0;

    this.equals = function() {
        let matches = Object.values(toiletData.entries);

        Object.values(toiletData.entries).forEach(toilet => {
            Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
                if ((this[key] !== undefined) && (typeof this[key] !== "function")) {
                    if (this[key] !== toilet[key]) {
                        matches.remove(toilet);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        return matches;
    };
}
```

In the JSON-file the values associated with variables are:

```
name = string, 
address = string, 
wheelchairAccesible = 1(yes) or 0(no),
price = int
```

Comment: Is `toiletData.entries` an array of objects or just an object or what?

Comment: toiletData.entries is an array of objects. Printing it out to the console returns: [{…}, {…}, (many more) {…}]

Comment: I created a small github repository with the needed JS code
https://github.com/haardes/stackArrayProblem

Comment: It's better to include data and expected result in the question.

Comment: Do you want the search to use `or` or `and`? Do you want the search to include the toilets that match every search criteria property, or at least one property?

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem without including all the code, I was hoping to keep the question compact

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I want the search to return all toilets that match all defined criterias. The variable names in SearchCriteria is identical to the properties in the dataset. So if price is undefined in SearchCriteria, i don't care what value the toilet has for price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `toiletData.entries` is already an array, you won't need to use `Object.values` as it is redundant. Also, why remove the element from a copy of the array, just use `filter` that returns the result array for you:

```
this.equals = function() {
    let searchKeys = Object.keys(this).filter(key =>                       // get a list of available search keys first (for the sake of both clarity and performance)
        this[key] !== undefined && typeof this[key] !== "function"
    );

    return toiletData.entries.filter(toilet =>                             // then for each toilet data entry
        searchKeys.every(key => this[key] == toilet[key])                  // filter only those that match all the search keys values
    );
};
```

**Note:**

Change the `===` to `==` in `this[key] == toilet[key]` so that `"0" == 0` is `true` as I think the search terms are always strings and the data in `toiletData.entries` could be numbers. You may also want to create a (better) function that checks the equality of the values (maybe lowercase the strings, convert to numbers, ...).

Comment: Solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping through every property of `this`, create the properties to match, and user `filter` and `some`

```
var matchProps = ["name", "address", "wheelchairAccesible", "price"];
Object.values(toiletData.entries)
   .filter( toilet => !matchProps
     .some( key => this[key] != toilet[key] ) );
```